# Wpf's RichTextBox alternative

Tags: c#, wpf

`RichTextBox` lags really hard (at least under Windows7 64 bit)- I found several topics on many programming boards, describing this exact problem, but no solution. There's even a bug report on this issue for the WPF team. Some people suggested that setting `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` to `false` may help, but in my case it didn't... So - are there any good alternatives for the `RichTextBox` control? I need to be able to highlight specific words in large amounts of text and do this dynamically (during user typing, changing text).

Comment: Not an alternate that allows edit that I know of - from Microsoft.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be from Microsoft :)

Comment: Still not another I know of but I am pretty there is not another one from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try AvalonEdit ([http://avalonedit.net](http://avalonedit.net/)). Although it only supports text, it may be what you are looking for.

I have tried it and it is blazingly fast compared to the built-in WPF rich text box.

Comment: I found it like 3 minutes before you suggested it and currently I'm checking it out. Seems good :)

Comment: does it support richtext ?

Comment: @MindRoasterMir it doesn't look like it does. There's a demo of this lib on CodeProject that you can play with -- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor